# Store python datetime object in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

```
token=uuid.uuid4().bytes.encode("base64")
expires=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)
print token
print expires
con = sqlite3.connect(dbpath,detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO token VALUES ('%s', ?)" % 
      (token,expires))
a=cur.fetchone()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

**Table**
    CREATE TABLE token (token varchar(255),expires DATE);

**Error**
*TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting*

Comment: This has been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829872/read-datetime-back-from-sqlite-as-a-datetime-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never use `%` operator with SQL - it can lead to SQL injection. Fix your `execute` statement like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO token VALUES (?, ?)", (token,expires))
```

Actually there is another one problem: you can't use `cur.fetchone()` after `INSERT`.

Full example:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> create table token (token text primary key, expires text);

$ python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from uuid import uuid4
>>> token = uuid4().bytes.encode("base64")
>>> expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO token VALUES (?, ?)", (token, expires))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fdb18c70660>
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM token")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fdb18c70660>
>>> cur.fetchone()
(u'9SVqLgL8ShWcCzCvzw+2nA==\n', u'2011-04-18 15:36:45.079025')
```

Comment: ... which is documented in more detail on this page: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: i can persist into the database if i use %s placeholder in sqlite3. But will it be datetime.datetime when i retrieve

Comment: @Abdul Kader I added example session for sqlite3 and python. And you can't retrieve datetime object back from SQLite database without parsing because there is no datetime type in SQLite and datetime object will be stored as text.

Comment: I actully it stores as a unicode object. I want it to store as a datetime.datetime object. You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272908/sqlite-date-storage-and-conversion

Comment: Check out this section of the documentation: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters But this example doesn't work for me. And you can also create converters yourself: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/sqlite3.html#converting-sqlite-values-to-custom-python-types

Comment: To get the datetime object. Did something like this expires=datetime.strptime(row['expires'],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-speaking.

The string interpolation fails because you are passing two parameters to the INSERT string
but there is only one %s placeholder. What do you want with '?' here.

Perhaps you ant

cur.execute('INSERT....', token, expires)

??

Comment: I want to persist datetime object.. Which placeholder i should use so that i comes as datetime object not as string