# python: create and update a datetime field in a sqlite db

Tags: python, sql, database, time

I have a data structure that I'm iterating through:

```
SomeList = [[ID, VarA, VarB, DateC, VarD],[ID2, VarA2, VarB2, DateC2, VarD2]...]
```

The DateCX variables will always be of the form:

```
"2013-07-15T13:58:55Z"
```

I've also used the `sqlite` library to create a sqlite database:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect('test.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TEST(ColumnID INT, ColumnA TEXT, ColumnB TEXT, ColumnC DATETIME, Column D TEXT)")
```

I'm then iterating through `SomeList`:

```
for list in SomeList:
    TempID = list[0]
    TempA = list[1]
    TempB = list[2]
    TempDateC = list[3]
    TempD = list[4]
```

For the date field, I've been leveraging the `strptime` function in the `time` library to parse it in python:

```
    TempDateC = time.strptime(TempDateC, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

which results in the tuple that I'm expecting.

I then tried to update the `TEST` database:

```
    allValues = (TempID, TempA, TempB, TempDateC, TempD)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", allValues)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
 sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.
```

Is there something else that I have to do to convert the tuple I've created into something that can be inserted into a SQL db?

Comment: I think you do want to insert DateTime objects from Python into the field for SQLite - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272908/sqlite-date-storage-and-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

You have to

```
import time
import datetime
```

and then, rather than

```
TempDateC = time.strptime(TempDateC, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

you need to parse the date with a few functions:

```
TempDateC = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(TempdateC, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")))
```